# Shell script to replace string having space with another string

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I'm  trying to  replace following  string to  multi lines as following

```
setsid /usr/local/bin/Naming_Service ${OPTIONS} &
```

replacing with

```
setsid /usr/local/bin/Naming_Service ${OPTIONS_13016} &
setsid /usr/local/bin/Naming_Service ${OPTIONS_13018} &
```

I tried with this command

```
sed '0,/setsid \/usr\/var\/run\/Naming_Serivce ${OPTIONS}/s//setsid \/usr\/var\/run\/Naming_Serivce ${OPTIONS_13016}\n\setsid \/usr\/var\/run\/Naming_Serivce ${OPTIONS_13018}\n /' script > new_script
```

can  you please help  to resolve

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed 's/^\(.*\)\(${OPTIONS}\)\(.*\)$/\1${OPTIONS_13016}\3\n\1${OPTIONS_13018}\3/'  < script > new_script
```

- (...) - create groups
- \1 \3 - using these groups
- \n - newline
- .* - any character

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Its woring for me, let me know \1 \3 , how exactly it'll  work

Comment: \1 represents the first group, \2 is the second (${OPTIONS}), and \3 is the rest.

Answer (score 0):

For Your requirement use below syntax

Syntax:

```
 sed  -e "s/setsid \/usr\/local\/bin\/Naming_Service \${OPTIONS}/setsid \/usr\/local\/bin\/Naming_Service \${OPTIONS_13016} \&\nsetsid \/usr\/local\/bin\/Naming_Service \${OPTIONS_13018}/g" script > new_script
```